# @Primary JpaRepository not used for @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have the simplest of Spring configuration cases so I don't know why I don't find how this is done.

I have an interface

```
public interface UserService {
    List<User> findAll();
}
```

with two implementations

```
@Component
public class SimpleUserService implements UserService {
    private List<User> users = Arrays.asList(new User());

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(users);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Repository
@Primary
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>, UserService {
}
```

Note the `@Repository` is marked `@Primary`, so when I do this:

```
@RestController
public class SimpleUserController implements UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userService.userResources;
    }
}
```

it should be using the `UserRepository`, no? Instead, I get

> Field userService in com.studying.user.SimpleUserController required a single bean, but 2 were found:
>
> - UserDaoService: defined in file [...\SimpleUserService.class]
> - userRepository: defined in null

I get that Spring creates an actual class to implement the repository, so I guess that could be the issue, but is there a way to still do this?

As an additional question, how would I create two configurations, with one using the simple service and the other the repository? It's not like I can instantiate the repository in a `@Bean`-annotated method in the Configuration. I'd add an `@Autowired` to a private member of the configuration and return it, but that won't work for the same reasons as above.

Comment: The Spring Data bean is being created on the fly, so the annotation on the interface doesn't apply to it. Are you using Spring Boot? Can you explain the circumstances in which you want to use your "Simple" service and when the repository directly? (Generally, the point of having a separate `UserService` interface is when the repository shouldn't be used directly because you need additional processing of some sort.)

Comment: @chrylis yes, I'm using Spring Boot. The point of the interface is that I might be using a web service or something for it, but mostly it's just practicing at this point. The other use I can think of is in unit tests.

Comment: `@Repository` and `@Primary` have no effect on a Spring Data repository interface, those annotations are intended for bean classes of Spring beans, not Spring Data repositories.

Comment: @dunni not sure what you mean... `@Repository` includes `@Component` which is exactly what I need. If I remove the `SimpleUserService`, everything works as intended but I'd like to keep it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Spring Data interface you need neither `@Component` nor `@Repository`. The repositories are detected by a different Spring Data mechanism, not the regular component scanning from Spring itself. That's also why your `@Primary` annotation doesn't have any effect.

A solution could look like this:

```
public interface UserService {}

@Component
public class SimpleUserService implements UserService {}

@Component
public class JpaUserService implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository
}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {}
```

Then you have a clear separation between your repository layer with the Spring Data repository and your service layer, which uses the repository layer. You also don't mix regular Spring bean annotations and Spring Data repository interfaces, which will also simplify your work.

You can then e.g. move the `SimpleUserService` into the test source folder, if it should only be available for unit tests, and mark it as `@Primary`. Or you can use the `@Conditional` annotation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) to provide an even more sophisticated way to decide, which implementation you want to use.

Comment: Thanks! But what is the point of the `@Repository ` annotation then? I assumed to make it available as a bean, or else would it still be autowired? And just to make sure, I need to delegate the interface calls to the repository in your suggestion, right? And in the end, I planned on the configuration deciding on the actual bean. Again, this is all just practicing. I'm sure there are other use cases than repository for this construct.

Comment: Regarding `@Repository`, the Javadoc of it explains it pretty good, it is to annotate *classes* which you want to make available as Spring beans. It works the same as `@Component`, it is basically just there to distinguish regular beans from beans in the repository layer. Regarding autowiring of Spring Data repositories: As i wrote, Spring Data uses a different mechanism to detect interfaces, which will then also automatically create a bean instance of your repository interface. So you don't need to delegate any calls to the interfaces anywhere, this is done by Spring Data.

Comment: I suggest to start with https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ for a Spring Data tutorial. At https://spring.io/guides you will find a lot more Spring related tutorials.